# MediaPlayerNative: invoke failed: wrong state 1, mPlayer(0x0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, file-descriptor

Im having a hard time debugging this stuff. BTW, my setup is to play the video content using FileDescriptor data, Recording and sending of data to connected device is quite working well. But when i try to read the data, initializing MediaPlayer gives me that error.

```
03-21 03:33:02.111 27481-27481/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck E/CameraActivity: onPayloadReceived: STREAM DATA RECIEVED!  -------> I recieve the FileDescriptor data
03-21 03:33:02.131 27481-27481/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck E/CameraActivity: onPayloadTransferUpdate: STco  com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@f7a66429
03-21 03:33:02.131 27481-27481/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck E/CameraActivity: onPayloadTransferUpdate: STREAM PAYLOAD
03-21 03:33:02.134 27481-27481/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck E/MediaPlayerNative: invoke failed: wrong state 1, mPlayer(0x0) ---------> Error i encounter when i initialize MediaPlayer and START PLAYING the content
03-21 03:33:02.139 1755-9892/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
03-21 03:33:02.141 27481-27481/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck E/StreamMediaPlayer: run: fileDescriptor stuffs Exception failure code: -38
                                                                                        failure code: -38 --------> ERROR CODE i recieved
```

Here's my source for the media player

```
{

    activity = act;
    fileDescriptor = fileDescriptorVal;
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptorVal);

    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "startVideo: MEDIA PLAYER NULL,creating new instance");
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    }


                    if (!fileDescriptor.valid()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: FILE DESCRIPTOR NOT VALID  ?????");
                        try {
                            fileDescriptor.sync();
                        } catch (SyncFailedException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "run: CANY SYNC");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(activity, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                        mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "onPrepared: STARTING VIDEO!");
                                mediaPlayer1.start();
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: fileDescriptor stuffs IOException " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: fileDescriptor stuffs Exception " + ex.getMessage() + "\n" + ex.getLocalizedMessage()); -----> ERROR DETECTS HERE
                    }


                }
            });

        }
    };

    handler.post(r);

}
```